# How to protect cefsharp, HTML5 apps build with .net and visual studio installer

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, cross-platform, chromium-embedded

I built an app based on CefSharp with .Net and visual studio, now i need to publish this app as installer , sure the published MSI when installed on client it has the html and javascript file, how i prevent the client from accessing modifying it , may be compress into some cab file or whatever prevent the client to read or modify the js and html after installed

Comment: What about embedding the files as resources?

Comment: You could bundle your js and html to make it one file. You can Hash your web folder at each run and check it; close the program if it doesn't match. You can use ConfuserEx to protect you .net code that isn't part of the Javascriptinteractionobject. You should look into Wix if you're not using it. `this is a comment because it isn't really an answer` Have you looked at [Encrypted Web Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297106/cefsharp-accessing-encrypted-html-js-css-files)